# How to make glow effect in image view for a small part

Tags: android, image

I want to make a small part of the image glow whenever the activity is loaded. Do I need to take the exact coordinates of the image part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using a GIF. It can be loaded as an image and won't require any changes in your code. A smallish tutorial can be found in [this Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70F7V8eDNaM).